# Stock Photo that is not strict with the quality?

Tags: stock-photography

I've recently signed up to BigStockPhoto 
 
trying out to see if someone wants to buy my Pictures. 
I've discovered that most of my Pictures didn't "follow through" 
The very strict policy of BigStockPhoto... 
Anyways, is there a stock photo that is less strict (ahm, snobbish)?

Answer (score 15):

This probably isn't what you want to hear, but you might want to try and improve your quality before trying to sell your images.

The market for stock photos is pretty saturated, so unless your quality is good enough to pass through the policies, you will probably not be selling enough for it to be worthwhile.

That being said, there are quite a few [other stock photo sites](http://www.givemeareview.com/stock-photo/reviews.html) out there, or you can post them to flickr and turn on the ["Request to License" feature](http://www.flickr.com/help/gettyimages/), which offers them via [Getty Images](http://www.gettyimages.com/).

Answer (score 3):

To some degree, I would expect any stock photo site to set a standard bar for quality. There are billions of photos on the net...not all of them should be able to qualify as useful "stock". Quality is an important factor even in the stock photo market, and if you really wish to make some money on it, quality will become more important if you try to get more money per photo.

You might try to look at it a different way: If you don't meet the quality bar for stock photo sites, take that as a challenge to improve. Once you do start meeting the quality bar for some stock photo sites, up the ante, and work on improving more to meet the quality bar for better stock photo sites. Etc. etc., ad. inf. ;-P

Answer (score 2):

www.clustershot.com has no quality standards.

Comment: Chris is right! http://www.clustershot.com/rustyedwardson/photo481267

Comment: I wish I wasn't right.

Comment: @che - So you're claiming that photo is not worth $50? :)